# Network Shares of Removable Drives Disappear (Windows)

Tags: windows, networking

I have two removable drives. I can set the access rights so that they can be shared and used from another network computer, but when I start my main computer the next time and the drives are switched off, they seem to lose the share settings and I have to set the access rights again.

Is there a way to prevent this and to automatically share a complete drive so that it can be accessed across the network as soon as it is switched on the next time?

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser; see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/

Answer (score 0):

The long and the short of it is "No"... I had the same issue with a removable drive and there's not a way to do it. You CAN however, write a small service that will share the drive automatically on boot-up. Short of that, Windows just simply will not re-share a removable drive after reboot.

~md5sum~

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem, and after some research came to this registry solution that increases the number of shared removable drives that windows retains (why Windows is worried about not having enough space to remember unlimited numbers of shares is beyond me). http://forums.cnet.com/7726-6122_102-3230783.html#3230783